# Copying an Excel WorkSheet with Activex Controls and customizing inside the word document using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, activex

I'm working on a template document layout in Excel that has multiple dropdowns boxes and textboxes, checkboxes. Here is the thing the document has multiple lists data validations and those other controls.

### I'm able to paste the document with the data validation lists values, and I'm trying to get the values of the ativex control to be reflected in the word document as well as fitting the content properly within the margins of the word document. So far this is the code I have:

```
 Sub GenerateWordDoc()
 
     ' creates and initializes a word application object
     Dim WordApp As Object
     Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
     'Makes it visible and adds the blank page into the word app
      WordApp.Visible = True
      WordApp.Activate
      WordApp.Documents.Add
    
     'selects the range that I want to copy
      Range("A1:J52").Copy
    
      'paste the data selected in Excel into the word doc created
       WordApp.Selection.Paste   
      'Saves the file
       WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Environ("userprofile") & "FIlePathTest " &             
      Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".docx"
       
      'Closes the app
       WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    
      'quits the app
       WordApp.Quit
   End Sub
```

---

### and I have been using the following commands to fit the data in the word document

```
    Dim WordTable As Object
    Set WordTable = WordApp.Tables(1)
    WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)   '2
```

---

### and

```
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add    
    'Paste Table into MS Word
     objDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable _
          LinkedToExcel:=False, _
          WordFormatting:=False, _
          RTF:=False
        
    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
     Dim WordTable As Object
     Set WordTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
     WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
```

---

### for the dropdown boxes, I have this code(note.- this is only one method)

```
 Sub dropdownVariable2()
     Dim dd2 As DropDown
     Dim ddval As Variant
     Set dd2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 56").OLEFormat.Object
     ddval = dd2.List(dd2.ListIndex)
 End Sub
```

---

Can someone please advice/help mainly in the very first method I posted. I don't know if it is because the document is not a table. Although Word recognizes the paste as a table.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub GenerateWordDoc()
Dim ObjWrd As Object, ObjDoc As Object

'Initializes Word
Set ObjWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With ObjWrd
  .Visible = True
  
  'Create a Document
  Set ObjDoc = .Documents.Add
  
  'Copy the Excel Range
  Range("A1:J52").Copy

  With ObjDoc
    'Paste the Excel data into the Document
    .Range.Paste
    
    'Format the Table
    With .Tables(1)
      .AllowAutoFit = True
      .AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
    End With
    
    'Save and close the Document
    .SaveAs Environ("UserProfile") & "FilePathTest " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".docx", _
      12, , , False '12 = wdFormatXMLDocument
    .Close False
  End With
  
  'Quit Word
  .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

However, your use of Word constants in your code suggests you've set a reference to Word. In that case, you're already set to use early binding, which is much faster. With early binding you could use:

```
Sub GenerateWordDoc()
Dim WrdApp As New Word.Application, WrdDoc As Word.Document

With WrdApp
  .Visible = True
  
  'Create a Document
  Set WrdDoc = .Documents.Add
  
  'Copy the Excel Range
  Range("A1:J52").Copy

  With WrdDoc
    'Paste the Excel data into the Document
    .Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    
    'Format the Table
    With .Tables(1)
      .AllowAutoFit = True
      .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    End With
    
    'Save and close the Document
    .SaveAs Filename:=Environ("UserProfile") & "FilePathTest " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".docx", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddTorecentFiles:=False
    .Close False
  End With
  
  'Quit Word
  .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to use what you put here, and I still get an error that doesn't even let me create the file, but thank you for the suggestion though :)

Comment: I tested the document creation & update code before I posted it, so I know it works. The only line I didn't test was the save code - which is essentially the same as you already had. I have no idea what you have instead of "FilePathTest " - which isn't a valid path as it stands.

Comment: Yes, I know the path is not correct @macropod  I did intentionally.

Comment: I don't know if the issue is also because, on my excel file I do not have a table. it is a document that has many data validations and activex controls. In addtion to that not all cells are the size/order (I have many merged cells). so, if I convert the excel doc in a table it screws everything out.

Comment: There was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: oh yeah, I dd correct the typo and still I didn't get any effect on my macro running the code.

Comment: I get this error message:    Run-time error '4198':   Method 'PasteExcelTable' of Object 'Range' Failed.   I believe this is because of the same although it is selected as a table to be paste is not a table, and once it tries to use that functionality from excel it failed. so I'm wondering if using the word controls from excel is something that can be done

Comment: at least that main, I got it to work properly. (Yey!) but I use a different setting @macroprod

Comment: You could just use .Range.Paste, though .Range.PasteExcelTable works for me even when there are ActiveX controls in the Excel range. Besides which, after discussing .Range.PasteExcelTable, you said «Word recognizes the paste as a table» so I could only assume that code worked well enough for what you are trying to do. My focus was on how to improve the code and show how to resize the pasted table - which is where you said your problem was.

Comment: yes! and I was able to do resizing as well. now is just the activex controls, that won't paste. let's say now I'm in the second part of this post.